# D - module main is in file "main.d" which cannot be read when compiling using DUB

Tags: d, dub

I have following for dub.json:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "targetType": "executable",
    "sourceFiles": ["main.d"],
    "mainSourceFile": "main.d",
    "importPaths": ["src"],
    "sourcePaths": ["src"],
}
```

I have my `main.d` (with basic hello-world-like program) in `src` folder. If I run `dub build` I get the error mentioned in the question title. If I move `main.d` from `src` to the same directory where `dub.json` resides, the error goes away. I'd very much like to keep the sources in `src`, but that doesn't compile. How do I fix it?

I'm aware of there two questions: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573909/module-x-is-in-x-d-which-cannot-be-read-error-when-compiling-a-d-program), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888257/gdc-error-error-module-file-is-in-file-file-d-which-cannot-be-read?rq=1), but the situation is different from both of them. In the first one, the module that's not found is a dependency, which is not the case here. In the second, the compilation is performed manually and not via DUB (I've tried passing `-Isrc` to the compiler as answers to that question suggested, though, but it didn't help).

I'm using DUB v1.3.0 on Arch Linux (64 bit) and LDC v1.2.0 (but the same happens if I use DMD v2.074.0)

Comment: try deleting that `sourceFiles` line. It should be unnecessary with `sourcePaths` and might be forcing it to look in the wrong place.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: sourceFiles doesn't take module names, it takes paths relative to `dub.json`. `"sourceFiles": ["src/main.d"]` should work, but you shouldn't need to specify each file separately anyway. Look at NotSpooky's answer for the generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work if you use just:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "targetType": "executable",
    "sourcePaths": ["src"]
}
```